# Replace hover drop down menu with click event on ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad, click, hover

I have a 3 level menu working nicely on desktops.

The 3rd level is displayed as a drop down when the 2nd level is hovered on.

On the iPad, the 3rd tier menu is being displayed but the links require a double click to load, rather than a single click.

From reading up on this, I've learnt that it's because iPads don't support the hover effect but will work with a click event in jQuery.

Here is my jQuery that causes the 3rd level menu to be displayed when hovering on the 2nd level:

```
    $('#primary-menu ul li ul.children li').mouseover(function(){
    mysubnav= $(this).children('ul.children');


    mysubnav.css({'left':$(this).position().left}).show();
});
$('#primary-menu ul li ul.children li').mouseout(function(){

    $(this).children('ul.children').hide();
});
```

I'm not sure how to amend this for iPad support.

I tried adding this to the top of my document ready above the code shown but it made no difference:

```
//ipad and iphone fix
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||            (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
$("#primary-menu ul li ul.children li").click(function(){

    mysubnav= $(this).children('ul.children');

    mysubnav.css({'left':$(this).position().left}).show();
});
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    var clickHandler = (/iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? "mouseover" : "click");

    $('#primary-menu ul li ul.children li').on(clickHandler, function() {
        mysubnav= $(this).children('ul.children');
        mysubnav.css({'left':$(this).position().left}).show();
    });
```